# Navigation bar disappears Xcode10

Tags: swift, xcode, navbar

I used "Embed In" to embed my tableview controller into a Navigation Controller.  On the storyboard I can see the navigation bar and the back button.  However, when I run it on my Iphone7 or simulator it all disappears.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Select the navigation controller and enable "Is Initial View Controller"